# matplotlib: same legend for two data sets

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, comparison, legend

I am plotting two datasets in dataframes using matplotlib. The datasets are represented by different line styles. The following is the code.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 16))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 16))


plt.figure()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 8))

df1.plot(ax=axes[0], style='-', legend=True)
axes[0].set_xlabel('x')
axes[0].set_ylabel('y')
axes[0].set_title('ttl')

df2.plot(ax=axes[0], style='--', legend=True)
axes[0].set_xlabel('x')
axes[0].set_ylabel('y')
axes[0].set_title('ttl')

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, the sequence of colors is different for different line styles. for instance, 0 in `line` 
and 0 in `dashed line` have different colors. I'd like to ask for suggestions on how to get the same color sequence for both line styles.

EDIT:
Changing input to

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(501, 16))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5001, 16))
```

changes the legend to all blue
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky of a solution, but you create a list of colors with the same length as one of your dataframes, then assign these colors to each plot.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 6))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 10))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 8))

# to account for different numbers of columns between dfs
if len(df2) > len(df1):
    colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(df2)))
else:
    colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(df1)))

df1.plot(ax=axes[0], style='-', color = colors, legend=True)
axes[0].set_xlabel('x')
axes[0].set_ylabel('y')
axes[0].set_title('ttl')

df2.plot(ax=axes[0], style='--', color = colors, legend=True)
axes[0].set_xlabel('x')
axes[0].set_ylabel('y')
axes[0].set_title('ttl')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the answer. But it doesn't work when len(df1) and len(df2) are different

Comment: If the lengths are different, then I think you could take the color sequence to be the longer of the lengths. I'll try that now

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. I think then the problem is something else, probably with my actual data. I am not sure why it doesn't work

Comment: Updated my answer, the legends can be of different length, but if there's too many legend entries it might get cut out of the plot

Comment: colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,len(df1.columns))) helps

Comment: I think that would work if df1 had the most columns, but not if df2 does.

Comment: In that case we could use `if else`  , as suggested in your answer